# Shared library interdependencies

Tags: c, node.js, gcc, shared-libraries

I have two shared libraries. libjvm.so and file1.so ..

file1.so depends on libjvm.so file.

I need to find a way to link the two and execute a js file which uses few modules defined in file1.so . I do not have source code of file1.so

Whenever , i execute the node file , i always get the following error message:

```
Error: Dynamic Linking Error: ./file1.so: undefined symbol: JNI_CreateJavaVM
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please show the output of the command: ldd file1.so

Comment: @jimmcnamara: linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76ed000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7529000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76ee000)